# Terence Tao Analysis 1 Exercise 2.2.3

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm new to proof and need a verification. We are asked to prove:

(Order is transitive) *If $a\ge b$ and $b\ge c$, then $a\ge c$.*

This is some of the definition that I used for the proof:

**Definition 2.2.11 (Ordering of the natural numbers).** Let $n$ and $m$ be natural numbers. We say that $n$ is greater than or equal to $m$, and write $n\ge m$ or $m\le n$, iff we have $n=m+a$ for some natural number $a$. We say that $n$ is strictly greater than $m$, and write $n>m$ or $m<n$, iff $n\ge m$ and $n\neq m$.

**Proposition 2.2.5 (Addition is associative).** For any natural numbers $a,b,c$ we have $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$

**Lemma** The sum of two natural numbers is again a natural number.

For the **Lemma**, I have proven it myself. Now here is my proof:

*proof*. Suppose $a\ge b$ and $b\ge c$. Thus by defintion there exists a natural number $d$ such that $a=b+d$, there also exists a natural number $e$ such that $b=c+e$. Since $a=b+d$ and $b=c+e$ therefore $a=(c+e)+d$. By **Proposition 2.2.5** we have $a=c+(e+d)$. But the sum of two natural numbers $e$ and $d$ is again a natural number $f$. Therefore $a=c+f$. By **Definition 2.2.11** we have $a\ge c$.

Comment: Welcome to the site @joji!

Comment: Joji : your proof is well-written, and it is correct.

Comment: You might want to say where exactly it was justified that natural numbers are closed under addition. But otherwise, it looks great!

Comment: Thank you both of you!